# Camel Spring-WS. Setting custom SOAP header

Tags: java, soap, header, apache-camel, spring-ws

I have configured Camel SOAP proxy service using Spring DSL. Everything was working nice untill I found that I need to set a custom header inside  for SOAP response message.

I am using spring-ws component and latest Camel 2.10.0.

Here is an example of my spring route (I skipped some irrelevant transformations):

```
<bean id="ahc_binding" class="ru.fabit.ExampleAHCBinding"/>

<bean id="response_assembler" class="ru.fabit.ExampleResponseAssembler"/>

<camel:camelContext id="get_regions">

    <camel:dataFormats>
        <camel:jaxb id="main_jaxb" prettyPrint="true"
                    contextPath="ru.fabit.rosstelecom.webservice.models.smev" />
    </camel:dataFormats>

    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="spring-ws:rootqname:{http://fabit.ru/service}getRegionsRequest?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping"/>

        <camel:unmarshal ref="main_jaxb"/>

        <camel:to uri="ahc:http://localhost:9001/service/regions"/>

        <camel:unmarshal ref="main_jaxb"/>

        <camel:process ref="response_assembler"/>

    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

And here is the code for ExampleResponseAssembler.java ("response_assembler" bean). It is the last element in the route. And it's responsibility to get unmarshalled response object from some external service (from AHC component, actually) and assemble the proper SOAP response for overall route.

```
public class ExampleResponseAssembler implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        final Object responseMessage = exchange.getIn().getBody();
        final GetRegionsResponse regionsResponse = new GetRegionsResponse();
        final MessageDataType messageData = new MessageDataType();
        final AppDataType appData = new AppDataType();

        appData.setAny(responseMessage);
        messageData.setAppData(appData);
        regionsResponse.setMessageData(messageData);

        exchange.getOut().setBody(regionsResponse);

        final HeaderType header = exchange.getProperty("exampleHeader", HeaderType.class);
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelSpringWebServiceSoapHeader", header);
    }
}
```

When I set the Body that way it is parsed correctly. I can see it in SaopUI. But header is not there. That was a naive approach to set the SOAP header I guess.
And I can't find any relevant info about this.

Although I was able to find some JIRA tickets regarding this problem - [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4515), it is still unclear how to handle with setting some custom SOAP headers. And ticket is marked as "unresolved".
Maybe I need some override voodoo magick here (override MessageFactory, MessageSender or something else). Seems like a minor issue, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with a patch attached that might fix this.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4515

You could probably just implement your own component which derives from camel-spring-ws (not tested it though).

In your overrided SpringWebServiceConsumer add the setting of headers  (copy from exchange).
In your overrided SpringWebServiceEndpoint override createConsumer to create your custom Consumer.
In your overrided SpringWebServiceComponent override createEndpoint to create your custom endpoint.

Should do the trick, maybe with some other code around it.
Then just create your routes from your new component.

You might want to download camel source and look at spring ws component, it's not that much code in it.

Comment: Yeah, I already gave that link in my question. But I am interested in how it could be done using current production version of Camel. 2.10.0 . But maybe I will have to build spring-ws component from scratch...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the current implementation does not support multiple SOAP headers. I mean:

```
<soap-env:Header>
<MyFirstHeader>...</MyFirstHeader>
<MySecondHeader>...</MySecondHeader>
</soap-env:Header>
```

How can I submit a patch?

By the way, there is a workaround on Spring-WS side:
http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com/2014/05/multiple-soap-headers-in-apache-camels.html